# how to check exponent of a number in java

Tags: java

I want to check the exponent of numbers generated in my program. (They are generated like `2.333E-4` , when I print). I want to check which numbers are having Exponent smaller than `E-4`, which needs to be increased by multiplying with 10 till they reach `E-4`.

Any ideas how to achieve this? Even if someone can tell me how to extract the exponent , it will be helpful.

Comment: why can't you use `while(num  < 0.0001)num = num*10;`? Beware of precision though.

Comment: you want to change value the numbers value or just format differently?

Comment: i first want to check exponent value and then change the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Java docs: Double.doubleToRawLongBits](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits%28double%29)

> **Double.doubleToRawLongBits**
>
> `public static long doubleToRawLongBits(double value)`
>
> Returns a representation of the specified floating-point value according to the IEEE 754 floating-point "double format" bit layout, preserving Not-a-Number (NaN) values.
>
> Bit 63 (the bit that is selected by the mask 0x8000000000000000L) represents the sign of the floating-point number.
>
> Bits 62-52 (the bits that are selected by the mask 0x7ff0000000000000L) represent the exponent.
>
> Bits 51-0 (the bits that are selected by the mask 0x000fffffffffffffL) represent the significand (sometimes called the mantissa) of the floating-point number.

So you could get the double value into a long, shift by 13*4 (13 hex digits = 13*4 bits) to the right and check the exponent value that way.

This link will help with the decoding: [IEEE754 double FP format - exponent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to extract the exponent is to use the logarithm (base 10) function (Math.log10(double a) in Java).

For the input value you give, it will return -3.6320852612062473. For the input value 1e-4, it will return -4. Therefore, here is what you could do (assuming that "number" is the double value you want to test in the code below):

```
while (Math.log10(number) < -4) {
    number = number * 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
double d = 0.01234e-4;
if (d < 1e-4)
    System.out.printf("%fE-4", d * 1e4);
else
    System.out.printf("%g", d);
```

prints

```
0.012340E-4
```