# Check number has exponent or not in java

Tags: java, exponential

I would like to check whether the double value has exponent or not. There is no such method in `Math` using which I can determine. I do not want to convert it to string and then use `indexOf()` or `contains()` methods.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give us an example of double with exponent, please?

Comment: have you tried to do something?

Comment: Could you give us an example of a double without an exponent? Last time I checked the IEEE spec, every double had an exponent ....

Comment: `if(isExponent(num)) return true` - Now you just need to implement `isExponent`.

Comment: @X-Pippes Op has already tried and that's why he/she is telling that there is no such method in Math and he does not want to use contains or indexof method string class

Comment: @luanjot For eg. I have Double dbl = 9.7561E-4; For this I need to check which has got exponent.

Comment: @user2889593 you don't need to check: it has an exponent.

Comment: @user2889593 check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495891/how-to-check-exponent-of-a-number-in-java)

Comment: Once I come to know the value (double type) has got any exponent while any arithmetic operation. I am able to convert into the desired format. My only question was is there any way to determine the new value has exponent without not converting to string then using contains ("E") || contains ("e").

Answer (score 4):

Internally all doubles are represented the same way. (They all have binary exponents, though you don't see those.)

Whether they are printed with an exponent or not is only a formatting issue. It is not meaningful to test whether the double *itself* has an exponent. The right way to test whether it is formatted with an exponent it is to take the string representation and use `str.contains("E") || str.contains("e")`.

You can use a [format string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) or [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) object to get some control over how the double is converted to a String. E.g., `String.format("%f", 9.7561E-4)` (number with exponent) returns the string `0.000976` (no exponent).

Comment: OP has mentioned in the question that he/she does not want to use String.conatins()

Comment: @javaBeginner Yes, but this is a non-sensical requirement of OP. OP must learn the difference between external and internal representation of data, therefore +1.